# I want to use this query in an arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

```
=iferror(QUERY(importorders!A:H,“Select count(A) where C = ‘Thailand Tour’ and month(H) = “&MONTH(A3)-1&“and year(H) = “&year(A3)&” label count(A) ‘’“,1),0)
```

It’s basically just counting to see how many orders I had in each month.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Of6cdFYaOzCFwPdZ4ABItD6dghMjHhafRWmDJWaznbg/edit#gid=711075203

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in **B3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, QUERY({importorders!A2:C, 
 EOMONTH(importorders!H2:H, -1)+1},
 "select Col4,count(Col1) 
  where Col3 = 'Thailand Tour' 
    and Col4 is not null 
  group by Col4
  label count(Col1)''", 0), 2, 0), 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @user198561 I notice that Cell B1 is/was intended as a dropdown (though the sheet itself is labelled "21 Day Thailand Tour", and the dropdown isn't included in our permissions). In any event, you could make reporting more flexible with this small change `where Col3 = '"&B1&"'  `.

Comment: I'm trying to do avg age now. First I tried to separate the Query but it's throwing errors and I have no idea why, it's been killing me for an hour.

=QUERY({importorders!A2:C, EOMONTH(importorders!H2:H, -1)+1}, "select Col4,count(Col1) where Col3 = '"&B1&"' and Col4 is not null group by Col4 label count(Col1)''")

Comment: if you use EOMONTH then QUERY needs to be wrapped into ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with average age?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Of6cdFYaOzCFwPdZ4ABItD6dghMjHhafRWmDJWaznbg/edit#gid=711075203

Comment: there is no column with age in importorders sheet so its hard to make an average of nothing

Comment: You may have missed it, it's AF column

Comment: I've worked it out...
=iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(A3:A,QUERY({importorders!A2:C, EOMONTH(importorders!H2:H, -1)+1,importorders!AF2:AF}, "select Col4, avg(Col5) where Col3 = '"&B1&"' and Col4 is not null group by Col4 label avg(Col5)''"),2,false)))

Answer (score 0):

Try

`=query(A2:H,"select Year(H), Month(H)+1, C, Count(H) where C is not null and C like 'Thailand%' group by Year(H), Month(H)+1,C label C'Tour',Year(H)'Year',Month(H)+1'Month'")`

This data applied to a pivot table might provide a more digestible analysis.

---

**Report Extract**

[image: Report Extract]

Comment: That's cool, thanks. I also didn't know you could write like this:

C like 'Thailand%'

Thanks again